# Prestashop : Country cannot be loaded with address->id_country

Tags: prestashop

When my customers wants to register on my prestashop, they get this message :

```
1. Country cannot be loaded with address->id_country
2. Invalid country
```

Prestashop version is 1.6.0.11, PHP version was 7 but I downgraded to 5.6 as I hoped it would resolve the issue, but it didn't...

Here is what I tried so far :

- Changing `Country:name` to `country:name` in countries
- Enabling "Restrict country selections in Front Office to those covered by active carriers" (disabled it back after)
- Changing PHP version
- Changing theme
- Changing the registration process type to standard (with this option, I got a 500 error after submitting the form)

Generally speaking, the issues mentionned here didn't work for me : 
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/256624-error-country-cannot-be-loaded-with-address-id_country/

Somme github issues provided files to replace, but that was for the previous versions and the changes were already included in mine. I really don't know what to do... 
Can somebody please help ?

Comment: Does this happen for all countries, or only some? Do you have multishop enabled? If so (or just in case), check the table country_shop.

Comment: It happens with a stored address? Maybe this address has a country ID that doesn't exist now?

Comment: This happens for all the 5 coutries that are available, and it's for new registration, not stored adress...

Answer (score 1):

As I look up your problem, it's seems not the server configuration problem, it is simply might be the country customer register with is not in your prestashop country list active?
you might find which countries is active in your store by this step:

1 go to your store database table

2.go to this table: prstshp_country

3.execute this query: SELECT * FROM `prstshp_country` WHERE `active` = 1

4. you could find in your shop which countries are active:
   [image]

if user register country is not in the list you need to add the country in your shop dashboard, click active

[image]

once you had active but problem issue still occur then you might consider about configuration problem

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem only with Spain,country.
I changed ''need_identification_number'' to ''0'' and problem was gone .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).